# Problem "password" from Reply Challenge 2019

Tags: python, counting

The problem statement asks to find how many strings of length N, formed only by 1 and 0, there are such that they do not contain a given substring (with only 1 and 0) of length M

```
f1 = open("input.txt", "r")
f2 = open("output.txt", "a+")

T = int(f1.readline())

for n in range(1, T+1):
  N, M = (int(x) for x in f1.readline().split())
  sub = f1.readline()

  c = 0

  for number in range(0, 2**(N)):
    number = bin(number)
    number = number[2:]

    while len(number) != N:
      number = "0"+number

    if sub not in number:
      c += 1

  f2.write(f"Case #{n}: {c}\n")

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

This is my try, but it's just brute force. The first part is just parsing the input

Comment: Have you tried absolutely anything on your own? If so, you could drop it down here and SO members may be able to help you fix your approach.

Comment: yes, sure. Just edited